# use multi dropdown dependency in laravel 8 with livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

use dropdown(select input) with dependency very simple with livewire.

we have 2 models.
state and city

in case we want when state dropdown has been selected by user , city dropdown shown and user can select cities without using ajax or java scripts jut with livewire
just with livewire in laravel 8.

install livewire in your laravel project

`composer require livewire/livewire`

create your component (example name counter)

`php artisan make:livewire counter`

Running this command will generate the following two files:

app/Http/Livewire/Counter.php

resources/views/livewire/counter.blade.php

livewire class Counter.php==>

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    public $first,$second;

    public function render()
    {
        
        return view('livewire.Counter');
    }
}
```

livewire blade counter.blade.php like this==>

```
<div>
    <select wire:model='first' name="1" id="1">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
      @if($first)
      <select  wire:model='second' name="2" id="2">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      @endif
</div>
```

use our component in every blade you want.in case we put it on welcom.blade.php

```
<head>
    ...
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    <livewire:counter /> 
 
    ...
 
    @livewireScripts
</body>
```

Have fun.If have a better idea share it please.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think, it should not work like this

```
php artisan make:livewire counter
```

You need to run

```
php artisan livewire:make counter
```

Comment: make:livewire & livewire:make both of them work . but better to write counter like Counter with uppercase c for counter to create component